# C# datagridview databound number display format for 10,000,000 value

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, databound

Hi guy I don't know how to format display value in gridview with databound to MYSQL database
right now my total column display 10,000,000 value as "1E + 07"
But I want to show it as 10,000,000 so how to do that

Comment: Can you provide some code? but anyway you can use `ToString()` to format your data as you want.

Comment: For example: `string value = yourDoubleValue.ToString("N8");`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as follows:

```
value = 10000000;
string whereverYouNeedToAssignIt = value.ToString("0,0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

and you'll get 10,000,000